# Getting ClasscastException at FlutterSplashView.java for one of my published APP

Tags: android, flutter, classcastexception

My APP is published in Google Play Store and it crashes in some devices. Is it related to the Splash screen? I don't implement any Splash screen so, not sure what cause this error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: 
>   at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSplashView.onRestoreInstanceState (FlutterSplashView.java)
>   at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState (View.java:20262)
>    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState (ViewGroup.java:4039)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState (ViewGroup.java:4045)
>   at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState (View.java:20240)
>   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState (PhoneWindow.java:2184)
>   at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState (Activity.java:1195)
>   at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState (Activity.java:1150)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState (Instrumentation.java:1321)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:3161)
>   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:180)
>   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:165)
>   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:142)
>   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:70)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1955)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7091)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this issue on [Flutter's repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47635), if you are using ***Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9*** or earlier, the recommended approach is to setup a Proguard rule that will not obfuscate the FlutterSplashView.SavedState class.

In `<your-app-directory>/android/app/proguard-rules.pro`, add this line:

```
-keep public class io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSplashView.$SavedState { *; }
```

Check also this article about [Flutter and Android Obfuscation](https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-and-android-obfuscation-8768ac544421).